# HP Envy 17-3070nr locks up

Tags: laptop, hp-envy

I am running into a troubling problem, and would like to ask if there are any diagnostic tools that might help. My laptop, a HP Envy 17-3070nr, is locking up if left on for long periods of time. I've checked the System Event Viewer, and cannot seem to find any messages (Errors, warnings) that might give me a suggestion as to the source of the trouble.

I blew away the OS when I first got the laptop, and installed MS Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit). It has a SSD drive, and about 16GBs of RAM. It also has an Intel i7 processor.

The scenario: I will leave it alone for a few hours, plugged in, with settings for High Performance; the video card switching is disabled, so it's always using the higher-end video card. Additionally, the fans are set to always run. I typically will have a web browser (Chrome or WaterFox) open, and possibly Media Player Classic. When I come back, the screen is on, and I can see the programs / desktop as I left it, but it does not respond to mouse or keyboard input.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you monitoring temps with software?

Comment: I have not, as of yet. I ran ScanDisk a little while back when I first detected the problem, and have been uninstalling what I thought was possibly some buggy software (HP's program requesting a power state change). It is rather warm, but then, it's an Intel, and it should be idling when I leave it alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is an HP notebook, you can test the Ram and Memory from the bios.

2 ways to get to the tools.

1. [Use F2 at boot to load the diagnostics](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01443317&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en), there are other tests besides mem and hard drive.
2. [Use F10 to enter the bios](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02097000&tmp_task=solveCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&product=5218406) and run memory and hard drive tests from there. F2 is better option but there is some good info at this link worth reading.

.

F2 screen will look similar to this.

[image]

There is an update for your diagnostics dated March 29-2012, you might want to apply this before you run diagnostics.
[Look under Utility-Tools > HP UEFI support environment](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=5218406#N784)

.

[Here is your support page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?product=5218406&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&task=&lang=en&cc=us) for that specific model.

Comment: Hmm. The timer stops counting down a few seconds into the Short DST test. Is there anything special about SSDs such that a Short DST test would not work?

Comment: The drive may be bad, Is it under warranty?..Not work?, Not that I know of, here is a document HP has produced for SSD's...http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02876562.pdf

Comment: I also assume you updated the diagnostic tools as suggested?

Comment: Got the latest diagnostic tools. Asking the question on Corsair and HP's forums, to see if either of them can help find the problem and its solution.